# My if-else loop runs only thrice while it should be running more number of times

Tags: python-2.7, loops, if-statement

I have just started learning python 2.7.1, and I have written a code for a Cows and Bulls game, in which you need to guess a four digit number by continuously re-entering 4 digits till you get the right number.
But for some reason by code just lasts for 3 loops max. Here is the code:-

```
number=raw_input("Enter the 4 digit number to be guessed:")
a=map(int,str(number))

def Guess():
    yournumber=raw_input("Enter your number now:")
    b=map(int,str(yournumber))
    i=j=k=0
    while i<=3:
        if a[i]==b[i]:
            j+=1
        elif b[i] in a:
            k+=1
        i+=1
    print str(j),"Bulls and "+str(k),"Cows"    
    return yournumber

Guess()
c=Guess()

if c==number:
    print "BINGO! You have guessed the number!"
else:
    Guess()
```

Comment: If i starts at 0 and i is incremented every time it is likely to only run a limited number of times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is actually no loop to keep asking for user input.

In your implementation, there are exactly three calls for the function `Guess()`.

Your implementation:

```
Guess() # first call
c=Guess() # second call

if c==number:
    print "BINGO! You have guessed the number!"
else:
    Guess() # third call

#end
```

Instead, you should loop while the user gets it wrong. Try this block instead:

```
c=""

while c != number:
    c = Guess()

print "BINGO! You have guessed the number!"
```

Comment: @PrateekTripathi In stack overflow we say thank you by marking the answer as correct. Check out this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: I'll remember that :)